# In typescript, what is the index signature identifier for?

Tags: typescript

What does the index signature identifier do?

```
interface IIndex {
  [something: string]: any;
}
```

Where would anyone use "something" again?

Or in other words, why isn't the syntax just:

```
interface IIndex {
  [string]: any;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that "something" documents the actual key to search the dictionary instead of just its type.  However, a default name of "key" probably should work in 99% of situations...  There are a few cases (e.g. ``[styleName: string]: string``) where a custom name can yield more documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess would be that this is for reasons of consistency and closeness to JavaScript.

Just like it's common to name your method arguments (even in interfaces), all arguments to methods, constructors, functions and indexers in TS must be of the format `name: type` or `name` (meaning `name: any`). *(simplified version of the story but I'm sure you get me)*

Since names and types live in different namespaces in TypeScript, an argument of the form `string` would be ambiguous. Remember that TypeScript's mission is to stay close to JavaScript, so interpreting the above as an argument of type `string` would be unacceptable, and turns out it is indeed equivalent to `string: any`.

Furthermore, while indexers could be an exception, because they can only be of types `string` or `number`, this has not always been the case (TS 0.8 allowed `any`), so another reason could be to facilitate migration to 0.9.