# Unable to understand ArrayLike interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I recently found about `ArrayLike` interface

```
interface ArrayLike<T> {
    length: number;
    [n: number]: T;
}
```

I am struggling to understand what `[n:number]:T` means. Is this declaring an array of type `T` and the size of the array is `n`?

Answer (score 7):

It's an index signature. An object can be indexed using a string or a number in typescript (ie `o[0]` or `o['prop']`).

This is telling the compiler that we can use a `number` to index into an object of type `ArrayLike<T>` and that the indexer will return a `T`.  The name of the index parameter (`n` in this case) does not have much relevance except for documentation purposes.

See [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515593/in-typescript-what-is-the-index-signature-identifier-for) for more information.